# Magento 2 disable delete product action from some admin user

Tags: magento2, user-roles, role

Hi i have create a new user role in my magento2 admin panel . in that role i have only given access to catalog . So once that user login to admin panel they can only update product and category information .

Now i want to restrict some more thing from that user . I need to block delete product , update product price and update product quantity from that users . How can i do this ?

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure about update product price and quantity, but you can restrict delete action by create a after plugin for `"Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\MassAction"` class `"isActionAllowed()"` method.

Add plugin configuration in `etc/adminhtml/di.xml`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\MassAction">
        <plugin name="restrict_delete_product_plugin" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\MassAction" sortOrder="1" disabled="false"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Plugin class in `Vendor/Module/Plugin/MassAction.php`

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin;

use Magento\Catalog\Ui\Component\Product\MassAction as ProductMassAction;
use Magento\Framework\AuthorizationInterface;

class MassAction
{
    /**
     * @var AuthorizationInterface
     */
    private $authorization;

    public function __construct(
        AuthorizationInterface $authorization
    ) {
        $this->authorization = $authorization;
    }

    public function afterIsActionAllowed(ProductMassAction $subject, $result, $actionType)
    {
        $isAllow = $this->authorization->isAllowed("Vendor_Module::resource_id");
        if (($actionType == "delete") && (!$isAllow)) {
            return false;
        }
        return $result;
    }
}
```